# Python--How do I write the value of a variable into the pasteboard in iPhone (iOS 4)/

Tags: iphone, python, ios4, pyobjc

I am running iOS 4 on a jailbroken iPhone 3GS.  Before I upgraded to iOS 4, I had installed Python on the iPhone and had found the following snippet of Python code to copy a variable (key in this case) to the pasteboard.  I then was able to open another application and paste the value into a text field.

```
out = os.popen('\usr\bin\pbcopy', 'w')
out.write(key)
out.close()
```

Since upgrading to iOS 4, this code no longer works.  I receive the following error message:

> sh: pbcopy: command not found

I looked in the \usr\bin\ directory, and there is no pbcopy (or pbpaste) command listed.

Does anyone know of another way that I can use Python to copy the value of a variable into the pasteboard?

I'd greatly appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: Before anyone says anything, jailbreak is legal as of the 25th of July and the Library of Congress' reinterpretation of the DMCA.

Comment: Unless you're in Canada, then breaking digital locks is illegal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the package "Erica Utilities" available in the modmyi repository (enabled by default) in Cydia.

Comment: That did it.  pbcopy and pbpaste are now in my \usr\bin\ directory, and my python program now works.

Thank you very much, matthew!